# Image appear after Refresh

Tags: javascript, image, caching, aurelia

I am uploading Image in my Web Application on UploadPage. I need to preview Image before saving Image on AddNewPage. I am storing Image temporarily in session to carry selected Image from UploadPage to AddNewPage. I need to refresh my page everytime to get new Image on AddNewPage.

Is that because of cache? or something else I need to do?

My code on UploadImage page

```
fileSelected(event) {

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
reader.onloadend = () => {
    this.Image = reader.result;
    //console.log(this.Image);
    this.storageService.setSessionItem("Image", this.Image)
    //this.Image = base64data;
}
return this.router.navigateToRoute("AddNew");
```

}

Code on AddNew Page

```
getImage() {
    this.Image = this.storageService.getSessionItem("Image");
}
```

Comment: Did the function `getImage()` called, do you got image from session ?. log `this.Image`

Comment: Yes I called the function and getting Image but old one. When I refresh the page then only I am getting new Image.

Comment: What storage you are using `localstorage` or `sessionstorage` ? `Open devtools > goto Application tab > expand local/session storage` and check the value. Is it old one or new one.

Comment: Its getting a  new value because now I am clearing local storage value when UploagImage page load . New problem is, it doesn't display any image without refreshing.

Comment: You don't need to clear the storage. When you set value to same key the value will be updated with new one. Do you got new image value in `this.Image` when you navigated to `AddNewPage`, and How are you binding value to html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using typescript file in Aurelia . Yes I am getting new Value <img id="Receipt" class="form-control" src.bind="this.Image" style="width:150px;height:150px" class="align-middle">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214793/discussion-between-sameer-khan-and-manpreet-narang).